# Webview tries to open all links, but it should be opened in a browser

Tags: java, android, webview, hyperlink, onclick

I am having a webview, the webview might contain a webpage with two different types of links. What I want is that, if the user clicks on a link which contains `http://webpagename.com` it should open the link in the phone's browser. If the user clicks on the second type of link, which does not have `http://` he should be redirected to a new activity. Right now what is happening is that, the links with `http://` are opening up both in webviews and browsers. But, the links not having `http://` is showing **Web Page not available**.

The code to handle onclick link in webview:

```
// to know which link is clicked
            holder.webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                    holder.webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                        @Override
                        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (final WebView view, String url) {
                            if (url != null && url.startsWith("http://")) {
                                view.getContext().startActivity(
                                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                                return null;
                            }
                            else {
                            Log.e("URL: ", url);
                            System.out.println(url.replace(url.substring(0,url.lastIndexOf("/")+1), ""));
                            return null;
                            }
                        }

                        /**
                         * Return WebResourceResponse with CSS markup from a String. 
                         */

                    });

                    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
                }
            });
```

**What should I do to make sure the `http://` links always opens in the browser and the other links open an activity but nothing opens in the webview?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs for `WebViewClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html), the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method:

> **Returns**
>
> True if the host application wants to leave the current WebView and handle the url itself, otherwise return false.

Since you're handling the WebView's content and the redirects to Activities, this method should explicitly return `true`, rather than the `super` method's return value.

From your description and code, it doesn't appear that you need to override the `shouldInterceptRequest()` method.

```
holder.webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            if (url != null && url.startsWith("http://"))
            {
                view.getContext().startActivity(
                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e("URL: ", url);
                System.out.println(url.replace(url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1), ""));
                // Start your app's Activity here
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I changed return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url); to return true; but its the same. Did not help me

Comment: Yeah, I just had a closer look at your code. It's a little wonky. You shouldn't be setting another `WebViewClient` inside the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method. Override both methods you need in one client, and set it one time.

Comment: I mean, if its an http url, the url is opening up in the browser as expected, but if it a non http link then it shows up the page not found in the webview itself

Comment: Oops, you're right. I wasn't thinking. Since you're handling both cases, the method should return `true` no matter what, so take the `return`s out of the `if-else` and put `return true;` at the method's end.

Comment: Its working thanks! I have edited your answer with the new code